# non matching metric while compairing mutiple metrics with unique lable

Tags: prometheus

I have 2 metrics like:

```
metric1{lable1="a",label2,...}
metric1{lable1="b",label2,...}
metric2{lable1="a",label2,...}
```

Expected Result:

```
metric1{label1="b"}
```

as the matching label in `metric2` is not present.

> What is PromQL for the above expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`metric1 unless metric2`?

Or, if you only want to match on a subset of labels, `metric1 unless on(label1, label2) metric2`.